# Inject other parameters to an action when using controllers in classes pattern?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, silex

I have a class called *ApplicationDecorator*, which inherits *Application* and adds some often used methods.

At the moment each controller action contains at the beginning a line like

```
$appDec = new ApplicationDecorator($app);
```

Is it possible to tell Silex to pass the instance as parameter to the action like it is done for *Application* and *Request*?

So it would look like the following:

```
public function switchAction(ApplicationDecorator $appDec, Request $request) {
```

I am already using [Controllers in classes](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#controllers-in-classes) and want to inject an inherited class of *Application*.

> You can use Request and Silex\Application type hints to get $request
>   and $app injected.

At the moment only *Request* and *Application* are supported.
Is there any possibility to extend the possible values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [controllers in classes](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#controllers-in-classes):

```
$app->get('/', 'Igorw\\Foo::bar');

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

namespace Igorw
{
  class Foo
  {
    public function bar(Request $request, Application $app)
    {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already using controller in classes. I am searching for a method to inject an inherited class as parameter to the action. Updated question.