# Best practice to initialize common controller variables?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, silex

I am creating a small web application and have some controllers with similar base functionality like user profile retrieving and similar.

At the moment each action have calls to these methods.
I want to move them to get a better code structure.

But I am not sure what the best practice would be. In my opinion there are two approaches:

- create method in parent abstract controller and call them from each inherited controller
- use before filter (can it access class variables?)
- (using `connect` method)

There is one requirement for the "base" controller, it must receive an instance of Silex Application.

I hope there is a more easier way to do it.
Thanks in advance for every hints.

Comment: I'd go with the parent abstract base controller personally - seems like the best fit to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with something like this:

```
class BaseController {
    $user = null;

    public function __contruct() {
        $this->user = someFunctionToGetUser();
    }
}

class Controller1 extends BaseController {
    public function someFunction1() {
        // $this->user is set and accessible here
    }
}

class Controller2 extends BaseController {
    public function someFunction2() {
        // $this->user is set and accessible here too
    }
}

class Controller3 extends BaseController {
    public function someFunction3() {
        // $this->user is set and accessible here too also
    }
}
```

Obviously I have no idea about your current architecture or current code but you get the idea.

EDIT:

Updated with regards to the Silex requirement.

I actually have an API written in Silex. The front controller for the application is in /web/index.php. index.php looks like this:

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap.php';
$app->run();
```

bootstrap.php looks like this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Silex\Application();
require APP_ROUTES . 'Ranges.php';
return $app;
```

And an example set up of Ranges.php is:

```
$app->get('/ranges', function () use ($app) {
    // some code to generate results
    return $app->json($results);
}
```

You could easily set your classes up to use $app (the silex instance) up in the same way I did for the routes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added a new information to my question. I need an instance of Silex Application in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [controlles in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629873/how-to-pass-an-inherited-class-of-application-as-parameter-for-action/21632802#21632802) and use parent classes with this structure

```
class ParentSample
{
  protected $app = null;

  public function __construct(Application $app=null) {
    if (!is_null($app)) {
        $this->initialize($app);
    }
  }

  protected function initialize(Application $app)
  {
    $this->app = $app;
  }
}
```

In the extending classes the controllers extends `initialize()` if needed and call it first within the controller:

```
class SubClass extends ParentClass
{
  protected function initialize(Application $app)
  {
    parent::initialize($app);

    // further initialization
  }

  public functin ControllerSample(Application $app)
  {
    $this->initialize($app);

    // controller response ... 
  }
}
```